# CSS floating div takes no width space

Tags: css, css-float

I have a very, i think basic, question regarding CSS with floating div objects.

i have 5 divs Div1, Div2, Div3, Div4 and Div5 and what i am trying to do is the following

1. Div1 float to left
2. Div2, 3, 4, 5 float to the right (in the same order, so will have Div2 displayed at the very right)
3. have Div3 overlay on top of Div2
   4 Div4 and Div5 would shift accordingly

but I am having a trouble positioning Div4 and Div5 right beside Div2 because the Div3 is still take it's place so it leaves a big white space in btw.

any suggestion?

Comment: Could you add a sketch or something showing what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsbin.com/ipune4/2) what you're looking for? Or maybe [this](http://jsbin.com/ipune4/3)?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ipune4/3 is exactly what i was looking for, but i thought there would be a better way of doing it. But thanks a lot!!